# Create file descriptor which outputs to multiple targets

Tags: bash, output, file-descriptor

I'm writing a script, and the majority of its output is best sent to the log file, but I would like to 'opt in' certain commands to console output, e.g. explicit script status/feedback messages.

I have created three named file descriptors: one for the terminal, one for the log, and one for both the terminal and log. I have tried to use `tee` to send input to `$both` and have it reach both `$term` and `$log`, but this seems to have the effect of reordering the output. Is there a way to achieve the above but preserve the output order?

```sh
# Create FD 'term' with target == stdout's current target
exec {term}>&1

# Create FD 'log' with target == ./my-log.txt
exec {log}>"$log_path"

# Attempt to use tee to split output off into $log FD and send stdout to $term FD
exec {both}> >(tee -a "/dev/fd/$log" 1>&$term)

# Set stdout and stderr to route to $log FD
exec 1>&$log 2>&$log

            echo 1 - example output of command
1>&$both    echo 2 - script feedback/status
            echo 3 - example output of command
1>&$both    echo 4 - script feedback/status
            echo 5 - example output of command

# stdout:
#   2 - script feedback/status
#   4 - script feedback/status

# $log_path:
#   1 - example output of command
#   3 - example output of command
#   5 - example output of command
#   2 - script feedback/status
#   4 - script feedback/status
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you send output to `both`, `bash` doesn't wait until `tee` actually writes it out before it moves on to the next line, so you end up with a race condition of `bash` and `tee` making unsynchronized writes to `log`. Unless you have a good reason to need a single FD, the simplest and best solution is probably to just do this instead:

```
exec {term}>&1 >"$log_path" 2>&1
echo 1 - example output of command
echo 2 - script feedback/status | tee "/dev/fd/$term"
echo 3 - example output of command
echo 4 - script feedback/status | tee "/dev/fd/$term"
echo 5 - example output of command
```

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the way the commands were executed, and assumed that they were synchronous. Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answer, you can further define `echo2` function :

```
echo2(){
    echo "$@" | tee "/dev/fd/$term"
}

exec {term}>&1 >"$log_path" 2>&1

echo  1 - example output of command
echo2 2 - script feedback/status
echo  3 - example output of command
echo2 4 - script feedback/status
echo  5 - example output of command
```